# WPF- Running a method after MainWindow constructor has completed

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to run a method post MainWindow construction that will edit a Textblock text I have. However, when I call the method in the constructor it completes before the window loads, meaning any and all text changes aren't done. I'm at a loss as to how to run the method once the window has fully loaded without calling it in the constructor. Here is the code I currently have:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    public void WriteBios() {

        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();

        timer.Start();
        while (timer.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                MainText.Text = "_";
                MainText.Text = "";
                i++;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Stopwatch is not a timer. Use a DispatcherTimer instead, and update your UI in its Tick event handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The window class has a `Loaded` event that you can subscribe to. That should solve your problem.

Comment: That being said, it looks from your snippet like you might not be using the MVVM pattern despite the fact that you are using WPF. This really not advisable.